# changing css directive with css files that comes from the thems directory?

Tags: asp.net, css, caching

in direct regards to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265256/css-file-cache-dot-being-cleared-after-new-version-uploaded-to-server).

my css files are located in the app_themes directory.

so im not the one adding the reference to them in the master page.
so how can i implement the solution they gave me in my last question?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Files in the app_themes directory has been a thorn in my side as well for this reason, and also because of not being able to control the load order.

I am not sure how to access them programmatically, at least not as objects.

The load order is alphabetical, so I have in the past just put a number in front of all of the style sheets to indicate load order, like I would name the files **1_Stylesheet.css**, **2_Stylesheet.css**, and so on.

You could do the same thing, and just build the version number into the file name to force the cache to get the new files, so each time you have a new version you just rename the file **1_Stylesheet_v1.css**, **1_Stylesheet_v2.css** and so on.  Since they are added automatically changing the names themselves should not break anything.

This is not the ideal solution, I would love to see a better one, that is not overly complicated.